# How to handle exceptions in SpringBoot ListenableFuture

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, future, spring-kafka

so I have a SpringBoot end point controller that starts like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Response post(@Valid @RequestBody Message message) throws FailedToPostException {
    message.setRecieveTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

    return this.service.post(message);
}
```

And the post function:

```
public Response post(Message message) throws FailedToPostException{


    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Message>> future = kafkaTemplate.send("topicName", message);
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, Message>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, Message> result) {
            LOGGER.info("Post Finished. '{}' with offset: {}", message,
                        result.getRecordMetadata().offset());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Message Post Failed. '{}'", message, ex);

            long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int diffSeconds =  (int) ((nowMillis - message.getRecieveTime()) / 1000);

            if (diffSeconds >= 10) {
                LOGGER.debug("timeout sending message to Kafka, aborting.");
                return;
            }
            else {
                post(message);
            }
        }
    });

    LOGGER.debug("D: " + Utils.getMetricValue("buffer-available-bytes", kafkaTemplate));

    return new Response("Message Posted");
}
```

Now you can see, that we are trying to make sure, if a `kafkaTemplate.send` failed, we are going to recursively invoke `post(message)` again for up to 10 seconds, until the producer memory buffer clears and the message gets through.

The problems are:

1. We want to be able to return failure response to the endpoint's client (eg: "Failed to acknowledge the message").
2. Is there any better way to handle exceptions from a Future in a piece of code like that above?
3. Is there a way to avoid using a recursive function here? We did that, because we wanted to attempt delivery of the message to Kafka for like 10 seconds, before sending it as an email to look at.

Side note: I still didnt use `buffer-available-bytes` attribute from kafkaTemplate.metrics(), I intend to use it to minimize the chance of this problem, but still need to handle the above just in  case of some race conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but I really like `Spring Retry` as a way to solve this kind of problem. It's a bit of pseudo code here, but if you need more specifics on how to do it, I could make things more explicit:

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 10, value = KafkaSendException.class)
public Response post(Message message) throws FailedToPostException{
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Message>> future = kafkaTemplate.send("topicName", message);

    try {
        future.get(1. TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch(SomeException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Message Post Failed. '{}'", ex.getCause().getMessage(), ex);
        throw ex;
    }

    LOGGER.info("Post Finished. '{}' with offset: {}", message,
                        result.getRecordMetadata().offset());

}
```

Effectively does the same thing without recursing. I wouldn't recommend recursing code for error handling.

The controller should be able to massage the actual `KafkaSendException` with a nice `@ExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Thanks! Works with adaptations.